# How to get phpinfo() variables from php programmatically?

Tags: configuration, php

I am attempting to get a list of dependable(consistent across requests) list of "hidden" constants in PHP(as in, the client-side won't know about it in most cases without hacking).

Some of the things I am interested in is the following:

1. `./configure` options.
2. I would also like the very first `System` value in phpinfo.
3. The loaded PHP modules(as shown in the Apache section)
4. The build date of PHP.
5. Registered PHP streams
6. Registered stream socket transports
7. Registered stream filters

How can I get either just a portion of the phpinfo or get these values as a regular string? Note that it doesn't matter if there if markup included, but I don't want to parse the phpinfo as that just seems really slow and surely there is a better way..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here you go:

1. `ini_get_all()` or `get_loaded_extensions()` **were the closest I could find**
2. `php_uname()`
3. `apache_get_modules()`
4. `phpversion()` **was the closest I could find**
5. `stream_get_wrappers()`
6. `stream_get_transports()`
7. `stream_get_filters()`

See also `get_defined_constants()` and [some more](http://php.net/manual/en/book.info.php).

---

As Chacha102 mentioned you can also use output control functions and parse the `phpinfo()`:

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$variable = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();
```

Due to the use of `ob_get_clean()` it won't mess up other output buffering levels you may be using.

Comment: I believe `PHP_VERSION` is a constant that would work aswell.

Comment: Yes, but I prefer to use the function. =)

Comment: I'll bet you in microptmizations that the constant is faster than the function. Then again, microptimizations are stupid anyway.

Comment: @Chacha102: My answer is function only, no constants allowed! :P

Comment: Constants are annoying because something they aren't defined, or PHP tries to use them as a string instead of a constant.

Comment: I was looking for something a little different (customizing the PHPINFO page by injecting a stylesheet reference, rather than extracting data from it), but this helped me a lot, so +1 and personal kudos!

Answer (score 7):

Most of the stuff available from phpinfo() can be found in constants. Try looking through:

```
print_r(get_defined_constants());
```

Or the functions on this page: http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.info.php. There are tons of functions to get information about specific extensions.

The following functions might be worth looking at:

`ini_get()` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php
`getenv()` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php
`get_cfg_var()` http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php

Comment: Well, I do not want to screw up the output buffering though because I may use it in the future for the actual pages

Comment: Output Buffering can be nested. That line of code won't screw anything up if you implement something in the future.

Comment: @Chacha102: `ob_end_clean()` will turn off output buffering (another call to `ob_start()` is needed).

Comment: Hmmmm .... Then how are you suppose to nest OB's if you can't break out of them...

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php says that you have to call it multiple times for each `ob_start`, and it says that it stopps the topmost output buffer, meaning the documentation contradicts itself.

Comment: The documentation is fine. You are reading `ob_end_flush()` page not the `ob_end_clean()` page. Anyway you should be using `ob_get_clean()` instead of `ob_end_clean()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late a bit, but basically if you call a shell script problematically to the php.exe

```
php -i
```

then you can parse all the information required