# How can i display PHP version, Zend Server Version and apache version?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server

I would like to print PHP, Apache and Zend server version by running a PHP script.
What all commands or functions are there to display these result?
Am not looking for `phpinfo()`;

How can I print specific values in phpinfo like php version ?
Am using Zend framework and Zend server.

I would like to display the version of Zend server and Zend framework.
How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069364/how-to-get-phpinfo-variables-from-php-programatically    Answers most of your questions, for Zend framework you can use `Zend_Version::VERSION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zend-version.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php

Comment: Thanks . zend version return as zend engine. is there any way display that it is running in zend server or zend core or zend platform ?

Comment: If you print a site with `phpinfo()` is there the information? If yes, you can read this number manually (I do not know a standard php function).

Answer (score 1):

You can get by

[phpversion()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) and [apache_get_version()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php) and this will return the version of zend engine not the zend frame work [zend_version()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zend-version.php)

Answer (score 0):

to get the version of Zend Server you should go to localhost:10081, and log in. Click the server info tab, you should see everything you want on that page.

Comment: Thanks, but you should check the source of that page at: Zendserver/gui/application/CE/views/scripts/information/server-info.phtml

Answer (score 0):

cat /etc/zce.rc | grep PRODUCT_VERSION